# Rotate multiple PDFs and write to one single PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have the following simplified code for pulling existing 8x10 PDFs from multiple locations, rotating them if need be (almost all need to be), then writing them to a single 11x17 PDF page by page...

```
while (Page < StackOne.Length)
{
    Files++;
    using (var strm = new FileStream(RenderPath + "Test_" + Page + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var MasterReport = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize._11X17))
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(MasterReport, strm))
            {
                MasterReport.Open();
                MasterReport.NewPage();
                var cb = writer.DirectContent;

                for (; Page <= NumPages * Files && Page < StackOne.Length; Page++)
                {
                    var ProductionEntry = StackOne[Page - 1];

                    var filepath = NetPath + ProductionEntry.UniqueProductId + ".pdf";
                    if (File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        var reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
                        var pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
                        if (pagesize.Height > pagesize.Width)
                        {
                            var ExistingPage = reader.GetPageN(1);
                            var rotation = ExistingPage.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
                            int desiredrot = 90;
                            if (rotation != null)
                            {
                                desiredrot += rotation.IntValue;
                                desiredrot %= 360;
                            }
                            ExistingPage.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(desiredrot));
                        }
                        cb.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1), 50, 50);
                    }
                    MasterReport.NewPage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the page rendered doesn't have the pages rotated as they should be, I've verified the height > width branch is indeed being taken but the pages returned are still 8x10 instead of 10x8 written on each 11x17 page.

I searched around for a question this specific but couldn't find one that wasn't just writing to another file or the entire page instead of to a specific location on an 11x17 sheet.

**EDIT**: So with a little experimenting and looking at other examples I'm able to rotate the 8x10 page and write it to my 11x17 but unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to place it exactly where I want it here's the relevant code snippet:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
var tm = new AffineTransform(1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, x, y);
if (reader.GetPageSize(1).Height > reader.GetPageSize(1).Width)
    tm.SetTransform(0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSize(1).Height);
writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1), tm);
```

Comment: While PdfCopy is the recommended way of going about this, I couldn't find any documentation supporting writing multiple pages to one single page  let alone rotating. DirectContent appeared to be the only way to do so. (Also http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/create-booklet-a4-document)

Comment: `PdfCopy` is recommended if you want to have the pages as original as possible, but you are interested in changing it by scaling and arranginget with multiple other pages.

Comment: @mkl That was my impression as well, thanks for verifying.

Comment: @mkl Added bounty if you have any ideas I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: So you say you cannot place it where you want, can you elaborate?

Comment: Added answer below but yes absolutely, I have a new 11x17 PDF that I've created in a filestream and I want to read in an 8x10 PDF from another location, rotate it, and place it at the top of my page, then pull in another and put it below that one on the same page then go to next page and repeat. In order to do this I need to define where on the page these 8x10 pages will go hence "place where I want".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so after tons of searching and sifting through code it appears the answer was quite simple (as usual), as shown above my initial problem was putting a rotate tag on the page didn't actually rotate the page as I expected. After learning about the option of specifying a matrix for the pdftemplate it was pretty simple here's the working code:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
var tm = new AffineTransform();
if (reader.GetPageSize(1).Height > reader.GetPageSize(1).Width)
    tm.SetTransform(0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSize(1).Height);
tm.Concatenate(new AffineTransform(1f, 0, 0, 1f, y, x));
writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1), tm);
```

P.S. http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf P: 162 (143 in physical form) for those who aren't fresh out of algebra

**EDIT**: As @mkl has stated below the following is really only applicable for rotate entries of 0° or 90° if you have pages at 180° or 270° this code will need some modifications. Also any annotations in the original will be lost.

Comment: In some cases the result might still be different from your expectations: The source page might e.g. have a 180° **Rotate** entry; in that case your copy is drawn upside-down while the original file is shown correctly. Essentially your code is good for source **Rotate** entries of 0° and 90° but not for 180° and 270°. If the source uses a non-default **UserUnit**, you likely will get a scaled-down copy; it is very uncommon, though, to change that value for page sizes like yours. Furthermore, if you happen to be interested in annotations, they will get lost.

Comment: @mkl It's not applicable in my case but I definitely see where that could be a problem I'll add it as an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may simple add affine transform into AddTemplate procedure.

Like this:

```
                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(pageNumber);
                int rotation = reader.getPageRotation(pageNumber);

                PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);

                if (rotation == 270)
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 1f, -1f, 0, reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber).getWidth(), 0);
                else if (rotation == 90) {
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber).getHeight());
                } else {
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                }
```

Its java, but I think it is not a problem.

Comment: Your solution still misses proper treatment of the 180° case.